# Retrieving information from HTML using BeautifulSoup - same text appears multiple times?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have HTML documents in this format:

```
    <html><body><h2>Lorem ipsum <span name="datetime" class="0">dolor <strong>
sit</strong></span> amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
    <p>Morbi sit amet malesuada nisl. <span name="address" class="1">Phasellus <strong>rhoncus diam</strong> sit amet augue dictum</span>, 
porta interdum odio tempus.</p></body></html>
```

and my output should be two lists, one with all words in the text, and one with the span-name, if applicable, otherwise None.

```
    word list:
    Lorem
    ipsum
    dolor
    sit
    amet
    consectetur
    adipiscing
    elit
    Morbi
    sit
    amet
    malesuada
    nisl
    Phasellus
    rhoncus
    diam
    sit
    amet
    augue
    dictum
    porta
    interdum
    odio
    tempus
```

```
    name list:
    None
    None
    datetime
    datetime
    None
    None
    None
    None
    None
    None
    None
    None
    None
    address
    address
    address
    None
    None
    None
    None
    None
    None
    None
    None
```

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

input_file = BeautifulSoup(open("ex2.html", 'r'), 'lxml')
tags = input_file.find_all()

word_list = []
name_list = []
translator = str.maketrans(":[];.,#&*\\/", "           ")

for tag in tags:
    try:
        name = tag.attrs['name']
    except:
        name = None
    words = tag.text.translate(translator)
    words = words.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        if words != '':
            word_list.append(word)
            name_list.append(name)

print(word_list)
print(name_list)
```

My output:

```
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', '', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'Morbi', 'sit', 'amet', 'malesuada', 'nisl', '', 'Phasellus', 'rhoncus', 'diam', 'sit', 'amet', 'augue', 'dictum', '', 'porta', 'interdum', 'odio', 'tempus', '\n', 'Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', '', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'Morbi', 'sit', 'amet', 'malesuada', 'nisl', '', 'Phasellus', 'rhoncus', 'diam', 'sit', 'amet', 'augue', 'dictum', '', 'porta', 'interdum', 'odio', 'tempus', '\n', 'Lorem', 'ipsum', '', 'dolor', 'sit', 'dolor', 'sit', 'sit', 'Morbi', 'sit', 'amet', 'malesuada', 'nisl', '', 'Phasellus', 'rhoncus', 'diam', 'sit', 'amet', 'augue', 'dictum', '', 'porta', 'interdum', 'odio', 'tempus', '', 'Phasellus', 'rhoncus', 'diam', 'sit', 'amet', 'augue', 'dictum', 'rhoncus', 'diam']
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'datetime', 'datetime', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'address', 'address', 'address', 'address', 'address', 'address', 'address', None, None]
```

The problem are that
a. some of the text appears multiple times in the tags, and I don't how to fix it
b. some words are empty (''), but even though I check that in an if block it still gets added to the list

Would be really helpful if someone could give me some pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the text by:

```
text = input_file.text.replace("\n" , " ")
words = text.split()
```

This outputs:

```
'Lorem',
'ipsum',
 'dolor',
 'sit',
 'amet,',
 'consectetur',
 'adipiscing',
 'elit.',
 'Morbi',
 'sit',
 'amet',
 'malesuada',
 'nisl.',
 'Phasellus',
 'rhoncus',
 'diam',
 'sit',
 'amet',
 'augue',
 'dictum,',
 'porta',
 'interdum',
 'odio',
 'tempus.'
```

For the other list, you could try:

```
tags = input_file.find_all("span")

for s in tags :
    if "name" in s.attrs:
        print(s["name"])
```

This outputs:

```
datetime
address
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem is, I need to access the name of each word, where some words dont have a span and are therefore None, and some words have the span names, so the second list would have to be of equal length as the first list.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I found a solution, sorry for wasting your time LukasP! Was trying for a few hours and didnt find a solution, but now I could figure it out.
If anybody is interested:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

input_file = BeautifulSoup(open("ex2.html", 'r'), 'lxml')
tags = input_file.contents[0]

word_list = []
name_list = []
translator = str.maketrans(":[];.,#&*\\/", "           ")

def recurse(tags, name):
    for tag in tags:
        try:
            this_name = tag.attrs['name']
        except:
            this_name = name
        if tag.string == None:
            recurse(tag, this_name)
        else:
            words = tag.string.translate(translator)
            words = words.split(" ")
            for word in words:
                if word != '':
                    word_list.append(word)
                    name_list.append(this_name)
recurse(tags, None)
```